# Reinstallation for Python 3 prevents Jupyter kernel

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

In an attempt to start over with Anaconda using Python 3.6, I removed my previous install using Anaconda-Clean and deleting the /anaconda directory. Now, having installed the new version of Anaconda, I notice that the kernels in Jupyter consistently fail, with the following error message:

`[JupyterQtConsoleApp] ERROR | Failed to run command: ['/Users/Sam/anaconda/envs/ipykernel_py3/bin/python', '-m', 'ipykernel_launcher', '-f', '/Users/Sam/Library/Jupyter/runtime/kernel-2368.json'] PATH='/Users/Sam/anaconda3/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin' with kwargs: {'stdin': -1, 'stdout': None, 'stderr': None, 'cwd': None, 'start_new_session': True}  Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/Sam/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-qtconsole", line 5, in  main() File "/Users/Sam/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qtconsole/qtconsoleapp.py", line 422, in main JupyterQtConsoleApp.launch_instance() File "/Users/Sam/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 266, in launch_instance return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs) File "/Users/Sam/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 657, in launch_instance app.initialize(argv) File "", line 2, in initialize File "/Users/Sam/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error return method(app, *args, **kwargs) File "/Users/Sam/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qtconsole/qtconsoleapp.py", line 393, in initialize JupyterConsoleApp.initialize(self,argv) File "/Users/Sam/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/consoleapp.py", line 334, in initialize self.init_kernel_manager() File "/Users/Sam/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/consoleapp.py", line 288, in init_kernel_manager self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(**kwargs) File "/Users/Sam/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 259, in start_kernel **kw) File "/Users/Sam/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 204, in _launch_kernel return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw) File "/Users/Sam/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/launcher.py", line 128, in launch_kernel proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs) File "/Users/Sam/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__ restore_signals, start_new_session) File "/Users/Sam/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/Sam/anaconda/envs/ipykernel_py3/bin/python': '/Users/Sam/anaconda/envs/ipykernel_py3/bin/python'`

Noticeably, I can run Python (v3.6) perfectly well in the Terminal still. Is there any way to fix this?